# Unhandled Exception at KernelBase.dll when Invoking my CLR Project

Tags: c++, exception, clr, unmanaged, managed

I get this exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x75374B32 (KernelBase.dll) in
>   LogLoaderUnmanaged.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80070002,
>   0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x74040000).

When I call my CLR project using this code (part of an Application .exe type project):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _tprintf_s(_T("Press enter to start logging messages."));
    _getch();
    std::string app("Application");
    std::string domain("Domain");
    std::string message("Message");
    UnmanagedLoggerClient::LogError(Debug, app.c_str(), domain.c_str(), message.c_str());
    _tprintf_s(_T("Done."));
}
```

The error is at the call to LogError, which is defined in my CLR DLL's header as follows:

```
#ifdef UNMANAGEDLOGGERCLIENT_EXPORTS
#define WIN32PROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WIN32PROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

enum UnmanagedLogLevel
{
    Debug = 0,
    Error = 1
};

static class WIN32PROJECT_API UnmanagedLoggerClient
{
public:
    static void LogError (UnmanagedLogLevel level, const char* app, const char* domain, const char* message);
};
```

In the implementation the method is pretty straightforward:

```
void UnmanagedLoggerClient::LogError(UnmanagedLogLevel level, const char* app, const char* domain, const char* message)
{
    LoggerClient::LogLevel logLevel = static_cast<LoggerClient::LogLevel>(level);
    LoggerClient::Logger::LogError(logLevel, gcnew String(app), gcnew String(domain), gcnew String(message), DateTime::Now);
}
```

Any ideas why this happens? I'm not really much of a C++ guy and I haven't found any useful information searching for this problem online. Many thanks for any input!

Comment: @HansPassant - You are a hero. I feel so dumb, not checking what 0x80070002 represents. This is exactly why it wasn't working. The output directory was not the same directory as the binary directory where all the dependencies are. Please post your answer as a solution so that I can set it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a very brittle way to get the CLR initialized, diagnostics are therefore poor. There's a "File not found" error code visible in your exception diagnostic, error code 0x80070002.

You managed to start the CLR, the exception code is a managed exception, but it could not find a file. Make sure all executables are present in the same directory as your EXE. Use SysInternals' ProcMon if that doesn't help, you'll see it searching for a file and not finding it.